# What are response objects sent through Kaizala API? string or JSON

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

Following is the response being sent

```
userIdToResponsesMap:
1.  10ce550c-4ee2-44a5-99d3-92552c9e8cfa:
    0:"["65431.35","12606.12","11637.09","4848.06"]"
    1:"["dealer-2","dealer-3","dealer-3","d-1001"]"
```

Above values look like an array, but in JS, usually arrays do not have the beginning and ending `"` (quotes). So, is there something else that I am missing here

Answer (score 0):

This is a json string. To retrieve the array you can do var array = JSON.parse().

In your example, following should work
var array = __responses.userIdToResponsesMap["10cde550c-4ee2-44a5-99d3-92552c9e8cfa"][0]